# Using SQL to extract an attachment from another table (Access 2010)?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Well basically I have two tables with a field which is the same in both table (As in the fields are both set to an attachment). Now somehow I would like to extract all the field from one table to another. When I try the following syntax the following error message occurs.

```
INSERT INTO Student (Photo)
SELECT Photo FROM Students_Record1;
```

**ERROR MESSAGE :** An Insert `INTO` query cannot contain `multi-valued` field.

From this error message I noticed that this got to do with the datatype as it was set to an attachment.

[image: Photo Error]

So I did the following code

```
INSERT INTO Student (Photo,Photo.FileData,Photo.FileName,Photo.FileType)
SELECT Photo,Photo.FileData,Photo.FileName,Photo.FileType FROM Students_Record1;
```

Which also outputs the same error as the above.

**ERROR MESSAGE :** An Insert `INTO` query cannot contain `multi-valued` field.

Anyone knows how can I extract an attachment from one table to another using SQL ?

Thank you!

Comment: This link has all types of helpful information on multi-valued fields. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-multivalued-fields-in-queries-6f64f92d-659f-411c-9503-b6624e1e323a?CTT=5&origin=HA001233722&CorrelationId=64eb2cf3-c4bc-4939-8751-e67f498d2b2e&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#BM8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delete the first field.

Would be

```
INSERT INTO Student (Photo.FileData,Photo.FileName,Photo.FileType)
SELECT Photo.FileData,Photo.FileName,Photo.FileType FROM Students_Record1;
```

Comment: It gives me an error stating that it;  contains ambiguous outer joins. To force one of the joins to be performed first, create a separate query that performs the first join and then include that query in SQL statement .